# Facebook Notifications Unsupported post request using JS

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Error occured:Unsupported post request. I created a fb app that will allow the user click the button(This button is in my app)to send message to the app user and notify the user receiver that he has a notification from app. I don't know if i implemented it correctly. 
I really need some advice and guidance about this matter thanks ...

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;             
            FB.api('/'+254111161401649+'/notifications?'+accessToken+'&template=NewPosted&href=http://apps.facebook.com/lglinktest/', 'POST', {}, function (response) {
                if (!response || response.error) {
                    console.log('Error occured:' + response.error.message);
                }else{
                    console.log('Post ID: ' + response.id);
                }

            });     
        }
    });
```

Comment: 254111161401649 <--- my app_id

Answer (score 0):

Solve it !!!! all i need is just to get the proper app access token